# CDI beans are always instantiated at server startup, even with @ViewScoped or @RequestScoped

Tags: jsf, cdi

I have a JSF webapp (Mojarra 2.2.12, PrimeFaces 5.2, OmniFaces 2.2) running under Tomcat 7 (I followed those steps to install CDI : http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html).

I am trying to transform my JSF beans with `@ManagedBean` annotation into CDI beans with `@Named` annotation. My problem is that whenever I annotate a bean with @Named, it gets instanciated when the webapp starts even though it has @ViewScoped annotation. To figure out what's wrong I have added the 3 beans below to the webapp (inspired from http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped)

A "pure" JSF bean

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class JsfViewScopedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()
                + ".postConstruct() invoked");
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".submit() invoked");
    }

    public String navigate() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".navigate() invoked");
        return Faces.getViewId();
    }

    public void rebuildView() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()
                + ".rebuildView() invoked");
        Faces.setViewRoot(Faces.getViewId());
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        System.out
                .println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".preDestroy() invoked");
    }

}
```

A CDI bean with javax.faces.view.ViewScoped annotation

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CdiJsfViewScopedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()
                + ".postConstruct() invoked");
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".submit() invoked");
    }

    public String navigate() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".navigate() invoked");
        return Faces.getViewId();
    }

    public void rebuildView() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()
                + ".rebuildView() invoked");
        Faces.setViewRoot(Faces.getViewId());
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        System.out
                .println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".preDestroy() invoked");
    }
}
```

A CDI bean with org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped annotation

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;
import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()
                + ".postConstruct() invoked");
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".submit() invoked");
    }

    public String navigate() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".navigate() invoked");
        return Faces.getViewId();
    }

    public void rebuildView() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName()
                + ".rebuildView() invoked");
        Faces.setViewRoot(Faces.getViewId());
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        System.out
                .println(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".preDestroy() invoked");
    }

}
```

When I start the webapp, application scope beans are intanciated as expected, but CdiJsfViewScopedBean and CdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean are instanciated as well since I get those lines in logs :

```
CdiJsfViewScopedBean.postConstruct() invoked
CdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean.postConstruct() invoked
```

Something is obviously going wrong right from the begining... I have added a web page to investigate on the behaviour of my beans (as @BalusC did in his showcase) and it turns out that the JsfViewScopedBean behaves exactly as on BalusC's showcase but those 2 with @Named annotation are NEVER instanciated again whatever button I push...

Here is the webpage :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    template="/templates/resosLayout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

        <h3>JsfViewScopedBean</h3>
        <h:form id="jsfViewScopedBeanForm">
            <p>Status:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>It's now: #{now}</li>
                <li>Session ID: #{session.id}</li>
                <li>JSF view scoped bean: #{jsfViewScopedBean}</li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                <h:commandButton value="submit form without ajax" action="#{jsfViewScopedBean.submit}" />
                <h:commandButton value="submit form with ajax" action="#{jsfViewScopedBean.submit}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton value="rebuild view" action="#{jsfViewScopedBean.rebuildView}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton value="navigate on POST" action="#{jsfViewScopedBean.navigate}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:button value="refresh page" />
            </p>
            <p>Messages from jsfViewScopedBeanForm:</p>
            <h:messages for="jsfViewScopedBeanForm" />
        </h:form>


        <hr />

        <h3>CdiJsfViewScopedBean</h3>
        <h:form id="cdiJsfViewScopedBeanForm">
            <p>Status:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>It's now: #{now}</li>
                <li>Session ID: #{session.id}</li>
                <li>JSF view scoped bean: #{cdiJsfViewScopedBean}</li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                <h:commandButton value="submit form without ajax" action="#{cdiJsfViewScopedBean.submit}" />
                <h:commandButton value="submit form with ajax" action="#{cdiJsfViewScopedBean.submit}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton value="rebuild view" action="#{cdiJsfViewScopedBean.rebuildView}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton value="navigate on POST" action="#{cdiJsfViewScopedBean.navigate}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:button value="refresh page" />
            </p>
            <p>Messages from cdiJsfViewScopedBeanForm:</p>
            <h:messages for="cdiJsfViewScopedBeanForm" />
        </h:form>

        <hr />

        <h3>CdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean</h3>
        <h:form id="cdiOmnifacesViewScopedBeanForm">
            <p>Status:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>It's now: #{now}</li>
                <li>Session ID: #{session.id}</li>
                <li>JSF view scoped bean: #{cdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean}</li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                <h:commandButton value="submit form without ajax" action="#{cdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean.submit}" />
                <h:commandButton value="submit form with ajax" action="#{cdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean.submit}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton value="rebuild view" action="#{cdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean.rebuildView}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton value="navigate on POST" action="#{cdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean.navigate}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:button value="refresh page" />
            </p>
            <p>Messages from CdiOmnifacesViewScopedBean:</p>
            <h:messages for="cdiOmnifacesViewScopedBeanForm" />
        </h:form>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

My guess is that either I missundertand CDI beans either I have something wrong in my CDI setup or maybe some conflict with other libs (I am using spring) but I have no clue where to start have it sorted...

Comment: The first one is incorrect. `@Named` and `@ManagedBean` are mutually exclusive. How do you verify, "*The CDI bean is immediately instantiated*"?

Comment: `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` and `@ManagedBean` cannot live together. The first one will be considered to be a request scoped JSF managed bean, if it is really declared like that.

Comment: When you use  javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped use '@ManagedBean. When you use import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped use '@Named as mentioned here https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/jsf22-cdi-view-scope/

Comment: Thank you both, I have updated my question and I now use '@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped' with '@ManagedBean'

Comment: Could it hy accident be that they are injected in an ApplicationScoped bean?

Comment: And show the webpage… [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje : no, I added those beans for test purpose and they are note used anywhere else in the webapp.

Comment: @Kukeltje : you're right, I added the code of the web page.

Comment: Print the stacktrace in the constructors or set a breakpoint and look where they are instantiated from…  maybe a spring config?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it solved (Thanks a lot to @Kukeltje, you put me on the right tracks) but I dont really understand the whole thing...

It was a problem with spring : in my webapp's spring config file i have :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.sarcomabcb.resos.web" />
```

When I moved the 3 beans to a directory not scanned by spring, they suddenly started to behave as expected.

Might help newbies like me...

Comment: I'd suggest to use Java EE instead of Spring. JSF and CDI already are part of Java EE. Only EJB is kind of non-trivial to install on Tomcat. Consider migrating to TomEE. Then you don't even need to manually install JSF and CDI.

Comment: That's exactly why i am trying to do (step by step...) thanks to your many contributions to this site. An advice from you is guideline ^^

Comment: Have you tried adding @org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy annotation? It will make sure the beans are not loaded eagerly